# Why use @media screen?

Tags: media-queries

What is the purpose of using `@media screen`?

I'm new to using @media queries and I don't understand as to why you would need `screen`.

`@media print` I can understand as it allows you to alter the code when it comes to printing a page but surely `screen` would just give the same output as using standard css? e.g.:

```
@media screen { #id {display:none; } }
```

vs

```
#id {display:none; }
```

Surely you would just get the same output so what would be the benefit of `screen`?

Is there another benefit to it that I don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not match when the current media is not `screen`, e.g. when printing or projecting.

You are assuming that `screen` is the default, and all the others are exceptions, overriding with more specific rules, but the actual default is `@media all`.

Comment: I kind of understand what you are saying but I'm still a little confused with how screen _isn't_ default as it is what you're originally coding on..

Comment: Well, a blind person would be coding on a device with media type `aural` or `braille`, and when I'm designing a web page for my mobile, I'd start out with `handheld`.